# Where old release of Windows_10_IoT_Core_for_RPi.msi creates .ffu image?

Tags: installation, windows-iot-core-10

I try to flash old version of Windows IoT 10 Core to Raspberry Pi 3.
I downloaded from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/downloads) the .iso with .msi installer in.
As mentioned [here](https://www.hackster.io/JiongShi/windows-10-iot-core-for-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-92b1a3) the `.ffu` need appears in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT\FFU\RaspberryPi2`, however there is a new `.ffu` file, of `Latest Windows 10 IoT Core builds`.
I searched with Total Commander and found one more file in this place: C:\Users\olga\AppData\Local\Temp\RPi2\msi\msicontent\Microsoft IoT\FFU\RaspberryPi2

*Is there some convintional place for `.ffu`, or what the conventional way of downgrade the Windows IoT Core image?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the default path that FFU install is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT\FFU.

[image]

If you want to install an old version please check if there is already a version installed on your machine at first. You can check the default path to see if there is a flash.ffu in RaspberryPi2 folder, if it is uninstall it via control panel:

[image]

Then install the old version. You will see the flash.ffu under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft IoT\FFU\RaspberryPi2 if install successfully.

> I searched with Total Commander and found one more file in this place:
>   C:\Users\olga\AppData\Local\Temp\RPi2\msi\msicontent\Microsoft
>   IoT\FFU\RaspberryPi2

For this issue, please check the path in the setup operation:

[image]

Comment: By the way, I want to check older release of Windows IoT core that will be compatible with VS 2015, but eldest release, I found in Microsoft site is Oct build, and it seems same 17763. Where is elder versions that are compatible with VS 2015?